# Reading Esri File Geodatabase (FileGDB) with OGR?

Tags: gdal, ogr, file-geodatabase

I have a file ending with `*.gdb`. I don't know what it actually is. I also don't know what to expect inside the file. I am trying to access it with ogr.

I tried with ogrinfo:

```
ogrinfo test.gdb 
ERROR 1: posix_spawnp() failed
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `test.gdb' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRI Shapefile
  -> MapInfo File
  -> UK .NTF
  -> SDTS
  -> TIGER
  -> S57
  -> DGN
  -> VRT
  -> REC
  -> Memory
  -> BNA
  -> CSV
  -> GML
  -> GPX
  -> KML
  -> GeoJSON
  -> GMT
  -> GPKG
  -> SQLite
  -> WAsP
  -> PostgreSQL
  -> PCIDSK
  -> OpenFileGDB
  -> XPlane
  -> AVCBin
  -> AVCE00
  -> DXF
  -> Geoconcept
  -> GeoRSS
  -> GPSTrackMaker
  -> VFK
  -> PGDump
  -> OSM
  -> GPSBabel
  -> SUA
  -> OpenAir
  -> PDS
  -> WFS
  -> HTF
  -> AeronavFAA
  -> EDIGEO
  -> GFT
  -> GME
  -> SVG
  -> CouchDB
  -> Idrisi
  -> ARCGEN
  -> SEGUKOOA
  -> SEGY
  -> XLS
  -> ODS
  -> XLSX
  -> ElasticSearch
  -> PDF
  -> CartoDB
  -> SXF
```

So apparently I do have the OpenFileGDB driver. Why do I get an error?

---

I am on OS X 10.10.3

My GDAL version is 1.11.1, released 2014/09/24 installed with brew.

Comment: Have you tried accessing an object in the filegeodatabase? You are asking ogrinfo to describe a directory and not a spatial object.

Comment: Where did the file come from?  Do you know what is supposed to be in the file?  
If it is a FileGDB, do you know what version it is?  This may make a difference.  What system are you using?  How did you install GDAL?  You should upgrade to the latest version of GDAL.  Basically all of my questions lead to the point of you needing to add more detail to your question to handle some of the possible variables.  The more detailed information you can provide, the better your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans how would I access an object?

Comment: You say it is a "file". Is it a file or folder? It should be a folder with a bunch of files with various .gdb* extensions. If it is a file, it may be a zipped file gdb. In that case, unzip the file and see what is inside.

Comment: Yes it is a file ending with `.gdb`. So it is not a zip, but apparently also not a folder as expected from a File Geodatabase. I assume there is something wrong with the file. I try to get a hold of the creator of the dataset.

Comment: copy gdalplugins to ogr2ogr.exe dir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not know why you get an error but compare your results with mine. Download first this file https://hub.qgis.org/attachments/8536/Trecks.gdb.zip

Unzip (it will create a directory) and run ogrinfo

```
ogrinfo Trecks.gdb
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `trecks.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.
1: Venedigertreck_3D (3D Multi Line String)
2: Knappentreck_3D (3D Multi Line String)
3: Schobertreck_3D (3D Multi Line String)
4: Lasoerlingtreck_3D (3D Multi Line String)
5: Trecks (3D Multi Line String)
6: Trecks_3D (3D Multi Line String)
7: umbalfaelle (3D Multi Line String)
8: Trecks_fertig (3D Multi Line String)
9: Trecks_3D_fertig (3D Multi Line String)
```

Select some layer and take a summary report:

```
ogrinfo Trecks.gdb Knappentreck_3D -so
Had to open data source read-only.
INFO: Open of `Trecks.gdb'
      using driver `OpenFileGDB' successful.

Layer name: Knappentreck_3D
Geometry: 3D Multi Line String
Feature Count: 2
Extent: (148016.066200, 199364.803000) - (152634.006300, 210556.171800)
Layer SRS WKT:
PROJCS["MGI / Austria GK West",
    GEOGCS["MGI",
        DATUM["Militar_Geographische_Institute",
....
```

Re-run ogrinfo without -so and you should see all the data.

Comment: I get the same results as you do with the sample file you provided.

Comment: Thus my conclusion is that there is something different in your geodatabase.

Comment: You are right. There is something wrong with my file. Your sample file and your description helped me confirm this. Therefore I accept that as the answer.

Comment: Pro tip: don't unzip, just do `ogrinfo Trecks.gdb.zip`

Comment: (or `ogrinfo /vsizip/Trecks.gdb.zip/Trecks.gdb`)

Comment: @ustroetz "GDB must be ArcGIS version 10 or later". So if you happen to have version 9...

Answer (score 1):

Try opening it in qgis and see if you can access the objects as described. You choose vector>Directory>click on souce type and choose OpenfileGDB or alternatively try to convert it to other formats using ogr. If it fails then upgrade gdal. If qgis can open this then you might be having two versions of gdal

Comment: I can't open it this way. I think there is something wrong with the file.

Comment: I had this issue. It turned out that my `gdb` file was empty.