# Reading File Geodatabase into Postgres with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, file-geodatabase, ogr2ogr, pgadmin-3

I have looked at other Q&As on the subject and none have solved my problem.

- [Reading Esri File Geodatabase (FileGDB) with OGR?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143577/how-to-read-esri-file-geodatabase-filegdb-with-ogr)
- [How to Import ESRI Geodatabase format .gdb into PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/83016/how-to-import-esri-geodatabase-format-gdb-into-postgis)

My problem is similar to the first referenced Q&A where my error says 'unable to open datasource'. I downloaded the test dataset in the solution and still did not work. My set up of ogr2ogr looks like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=pg.rambck.local dbname=projects user=david password=xxxxxx" \\source\gdbname.gdb\datasetname -nln v1_dataset
```

When I run ogrinfo on the test dataset I get error: Unable to open datasource 'C:\david\trecks.gdb'

When I run ogr2ogr on my set up I get error: Unable to open datasource 'host=pg.rambck.local dbname=projects.......'

OpenFileGDB is listed in the list of drivers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No idea really. What is your GDAL version that is reported by `ogrinfo --version`? Do you get any more information by trying to read Trecks.gdb with ogrinfo including option `--debug on`?

Comment: GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16

OGR: OGROpen(C:\david\trecks.gdb) failed.
OGR: OGROpen(C:\david\trecks.gdb) failed.
Failure to open datasource 'C:\david\trecks.gdb' with the following dirvers......

Comment: I would have a try with more recent version. I suppose that your path to gdb is correct and you have unzipped everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the previous answer alluded to it, but at least one problem is that you are combining your dataset name with the data source.  They need to be separate.  Here is an example from the **GDAL** website:
`ogr2ogr -overwrite -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=myhost user=myuser dbname=mydb password=mypass" "C:\somefolder\BigFileGDB.gdb" "MyFeatureClass"`
So, based on that, your string should look something like this:
`ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=pg.rambck.local dbname=projects user=david password=xxxxxx" "\\source\gdbname.gdb" "datasetname" -nln v1_dataset`
One thing that can trip people up is that the FileGDB drivers don't pay attention to `Feature Datasets` inside the GDB, so you shouldn't reference them in your file path at all.  I don't think this is an issue in your situation, but could be confusing to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=pg.rambck.local dbname=projects user=david password=xxxxxx" \source\gdbname.gdb \datasetname
```

between the gdb path and db name there is a space should be careful. If still not work, check your user settings in your PG project.